# NOTHING as String in PHP

Tags: php

How I can show `'NOTHING'` as string?

I need it to be displayed instead of showing empty string value as results.

```
else if ($colorByChance == 5)
{
    $color='NOTHING';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check it first.

```
if(empty($color))
{
    $color='nothing';
}
```

or perhaps (if it isn't even set)

```
if(!isset($color))
{
    $color='nothing';
}
```

Comment: its not If Statement change... Simply if i have $color='NOTHING';
as string when i do echo $color i get nothing. how i can show NOTHING as string when I execute echo $ color

Comment: Do you mean you want the word "NOTHING", or to display nothing (as in the value or NULL)?

Comment: `<?php checkMyColor($color);?> and it will output 
the color of default to 'nothing'` in that case function will never return 'nothing'. Only when you call it without parameters.

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov Yeah, well spotted. +1

Comment: @user1558490 Then just do the check that I did at the start? If `$color` is empty, it will be set to contain the word 'nothing' and when you print it it will print as you ask.

Comment: don't worry I did it by using simple trick as the following       if ($color == NULL)
 
{
 $color="NOTHING";
 
}

Comment: @user1558490 You realize that the second bit of code would have done that for you as well?

Comment: Yes, thank you its the same one that you already posted it. if(empty($color))
{
    $color='nothing';
}